# How set html attribute value by javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, tags, attributes

Consider a code:

```
<input type="1 == 1 ? 'radio' : 'checkbox'" value="myValue"/>
```

But it renders as text box input. It seem that javascript do not set `type` value.

How set html attribute value by javascript?

Answer (score 3):

Javascript engine doesn't interpret random HTML attributes as source code. Of course you can't do it like you are trying to do. Consider something like this:

```html
<input type="text" value="myValue"/>
<script>
  var input = document.querySelector('input');
  input.type = 1 == 1 ? 'radio' : 'checkbox'
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick, but less elegant, solution would be to change your `<input>` tag to

```
<input id="inputFoo" value="myValue"/>
```

and then put right after it a pair of `<script>` tags with type-changing code.

```
<script>
    if(1 == 1) {
        document.getElementById("inputFoo").type = "radio";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("inputFoo").type = "checkbox";
    }
</script>
```

Or maybe rather:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("inputFoo").type = (1 == 1 ? 'radio' : 'checkbox')
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML input type text is the default type that is set.
HTML cannot do conditional checks, thats the reason for default type being assigned to input.

You can achieve adding the type attribute multiple ways using javascript,
here are a couple of ways

```
<input id="inputTag" value="myValue" />
<script>
    var input = document.getElementById('inputTag');
    input.type = 1 == 1 ? 'radio' : 'checkbox'
</script>
```

or, use a container div to insert input html inside like this

```
<div id="container"></div>
<script>
    var div = document.getElementById('container');
    div.innerHTML = 1 == 1 ? '<input type="radio" value="myValue" />' : '<input type="checkbox" value="myValue" />'
</script>
```

If you are using server side rendering like jsp alike, you can perform the conditional check at the server side and render appropriate HTML without using javascript.